# Dual Mapping Preserves Linear Independence if and only if Original Mapping is Surjective

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, duality-theorems

Here is my question:

> Let $V$ and $W$ be finite-dimensional vectors spaces over a field $F$ and $f:V \rightarrow W$ a linear map.
>
> Show that $f$ is surjective if and only if the image under $f^*:W^* \rightarrow V^*$, the dual map, of every linearly independent set of $W^*$ is linearly independent in $V^*$.

I would like to say that a map is surjective if and only if its dual is injective - is this true (and how to prove if so!)?

In the first part of the question, I had to show (the fairly standard) {$f$ injective} $\iff$ {$f$ preserves linear independence}. So I would then be done in both directions since $f^*$ is also linear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right approach.

Suppose first $f$ is surjective. If $g\in W^*$ and $f^*(g)=0$, then $g(f(v))=0$ for all $v\in V$ and since $f$ is surjective this means $g(w)=0$ for all $w\in W$, hence $g=0$. Thus $f^*$ is injective.

Now suppose $f$ is not surjective, so its image is a proper linear subspace. Let $w\notin f(V)$ and extend $w$ and a basis for $f(V)$ to a basis $w=w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n$ for $W$. Define $g\in W^*$ as projection onto $\operatorname{span}\{w\}$ w.r.t. this basis, i.e.
$$g(\lambda w+\lambda_2w_2+\cdots+\lambda_n w_n)=\lambda$$ Then $g\ne 0$ but $g(f(v))=0$ for all $v\in V$ so $f^*(g)=0$, hence $f^*$ is not injective.

Comment: Sorry, took me rather a long time to type up my answer and I only saw this after I'd typed up mine!

Comment: How do you know that the image of a non-surjective map is a proper *linear* subspace? (Eg the map that sends everything to $0$...?) Or can you just assume this then use some inductive argument?

Comment: @SmileySam The image of a linear map is always a linear subspace.

Comment: Oh yeah, of course. Sorry, I was for some reason thinking that you meant a 1D subspace when you said linear... :/

Comment: And why does $g(f(v)) = 0$ for all $v \in V$? Is it because of the fact that $w \notin f(V)$ - I'm not sure I quite understand what you mean by the projection. Can you give an explicit formula? Thanks!

Comment: @SmileySam I've added an explicit formula. $g(f(v))=0$ because coefficient of $w$ in $f(v)$ is always $0$ when we write $f(v)$ in the basis $w,w_2,\ldots,w_n$.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. I didn't realise that that was called the projection onto $W$. In fact, are you sure that it is? A projection onto $W$ should have image in $W$ - this has image in $F$, the underlying field. Do you just mean the $w$ (lowercase) component? (Eg make the basis orthonormal, then dot with $w$.)

Comment: Those picky details aside, I now understand your proof completely, thank you. :)

Comment: @SmileySam Whoops, that was a typo. Meant lowercase. Note that in general there is no such thing as a dot product or orthonormal basis for a vector space, which is why we have to do a little more work than just doting with $w$.

Comment: Ah yes, of course (with regards to dot product) - that is one thing that I often forget in my haste! :) (Hence why we have *inner product* spaces =P.)

Comment: Easy to do with the typo - $W$ and $<w> = \operatorname{span} \{ w \}$ are very different but very easy to type the wrong one in the heat of the moment!

Answer (score 0):

I actually determined the answer shortly after posting! Sometimes just typing up the question helps as it makes you really think about it! :)

**Claim:** {$f:V \rightarrow W$ surjective} $\iff$ {$f^*:W^* \rightarrow V^*$ injective}, where $V$ and $W$ are as in the question.

**Proof of Claim:** "$\Rightarrow$" Suppose that $f$ is surjective. For $w \in W^*$, {$w \circ f = 0 \ \Rightarrow \ w=0$} (*Indeed*: Suppose not, say $w(x) = y \neq 0$; $f$ is surjective, so choose $z$ such that $f(z) = x$; then $(w \circ f)(z) = w(f(z)) = w(x) = y \neq 0$, which is a contradiction.] Thus $\ker(f^*) = \{0\}$, so $f^*$ is injective (as $f^*(\alpha) = \alpha \circ f$, by definition).

"$\Leftarrow$" Suppose that $f^*$ is injective. Write $f = i \circ s$ with $i$ injective and $s$ surjective, and both linear. Since $f^* = s^* \circ i^*$ is injective (by assumption), it follows that $i^*$ is injective. Since $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional, and the dimension of the dual space is the same as of the original space, $i$ must be surjective, since linear also. Thus $f$ is also surjective. $\Box$

Thus $\{ f \ \text {is surjective} \} \iff \{ f^* \ \text {is injective} \} \iff$ $\{$the image under $f^*:W^* \rightarrow V^*$, the dual map, of every linearly independent set of $W^*$ is linearly independent in $V^*$$\}$, as required. $\Box$

(I believe that this is correct!)

Comment: You seem to be missing a couple stars, e.g. $w\in W^*$ in the first paragraph of the proof and $f^*$ in the second.

Comment: Correct, thank you. Edited now.